# How to resolve Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked problem and fetch api in react

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
      character: ''
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
 fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people/1", { mode: 'no-cors'})
 .then(blob => blob.json())
 .then(data => {
   this.setState({
     character : data.name
   })
 })
 .catch(e => {
   console.log(e);
   return e;
 });
}

render() {
   return (
       <div>
           {this.state.character}
       </div>
   )
}
}
```

I'am getting this error Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input
I'am trying to fetch data from api https://swapi.co/api/people/1
Expected output is a name = Luke Skywalker

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Fix:**

[CORS Everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/) Addon For Mozilla FireFox

[Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) Extension for Google Chrome

Just Activate this extension once your browser starts.

**Depends on WebAPi Permission:** 
if `CORS` is not set/restricted to `same-origin` within the API then send an [Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers) like below

```
fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
 .then(response => response.json());
```

Note `mode: 'cors'` that means `cross origin resource sharing` opposite of `no-cors`. Give it a try if Not Sure about WebApi.